# In a UILabel, is it possible to force a line NOT to break at slash?

Tags: ios, uilabel, core-text, hyphenation

Example: My text is `@"This is a great UI/UX feature"`.

A better example: `@"5/17 of this quantity"`.

**Is it possible to force the line NOT to break at the `/` (the slash)?**

I'm looking for a general way of doing, since I have others sentences with slashes.

Comment: try to replace / by \/ ?

Comment: '/' is probably seen as a word separator and there may be nothing you can do about it. If anything the requirement for most people may be that it does break the line after the '/' so things look better rather than leaving huge spaces at the end of lines. Why not avoid '/' and simply put "UI or UX" or "UI and UX" or "UI & UX" which is how most people read '/' anyway.

Comment: @Colas please mention your expected output in your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a UILabel, is it possible to force a line NOT to break in a certain place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392888/in-a-uilabel-is-it-possible-to-force-a-line-not-to-break-in-a-certain-place)

Comment: @pNre My question is more specific. But, I admit that I have copied the title ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to use a Unicode character rather than normal slash.

There are non breaking versions in unicode for space and hyphen. If you were ok to change to using - rather then /, this using `@"UI\u2011UX"` will show UI-UX and not break the line at the hyhen.

There does not seem to be an equivalent non break for slash, however you could try another flavor of slash. e.g. `UI\u2044UX` will not line break but show UI/UX using the FRACTION SLASH. See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2044/index.htm.

I tried this just now on a UILabel and using the unicode characters will prevent line break. You just need to decide which slash or alternative you want to use.

Comment: I will try with the FRACTION SLASH. Thanks ! (see edit of the question).

Comment: Main issue will be if you are Ok with how it looks relative to the normal /.

Answer (score -2):

Try this...

```
self.label.text=[self.label.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@" "];
```

Comment: I want to do the opposite!

Comment: No, I need to keep the `/`. Actually, I use `/` for fractions.

Comment: @Colas i think then you didn't ask question properly. why are not sharing  your output and expected output. so that i can get exact your problem.